# Django form element does not render in the html page

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a simple django application to get some input process it and run a back ground process to show the result on a new page.

I have the view code as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = JsonTestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/result/')
else:
    form = JsonTestForm()
    return render(request, 'ellora/index.html', {'form': form})
```

The form class as follows

```
from django import forms

class JsonTestForm(forms.Form):
    jsonTest = forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "txtarea", "placeholder": "Enter your json script here"})
```

And my template file is

```
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>My app</h1>
        <form class="form" method="post" action="/ellora/compute/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Generate Test">
      </form>
    </div>
```

When I run the django server, the html file does not show the textarea. I look at the page source and it just has an empty line in the {{ form }} location. I was expecting

```
<textarea class="txtarea" placeholder="Enter your json script here"></textarea>
```

why isnt the form element showing? Also if I have the  defined in the template itself, is there a way to get the contents of it without having to use django.forms.Form.Textarea?

Answer (score 1):

forms.Textarea is a form widget.

```
from django import forms

class JsonTestForm(forms.Form):
    jsonTest = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "txtarea", "placeholder": "Enter your json script here"}))
```

should render the textarea.

Answer (score -1):

In your form class, you're using the widget `Textarea`. You need to use `forms.CharField` and specify the widget as `widget=forms.Textarea`.